# How to prevent GCC warning that function has no return when inline assembly?

Tags: c, gcc, x86, inline-assembly

I'm using a bit of inline assembly to load a function return value into the eax register. However, GCC squawks about the function not returning a value if it is defined as such:

```
char *trim(char *s);
```

This generates the following 2 warnings:

```
control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
No return, in function returning non-void
```

Hence the use of the weak alias below. Is there a better method to prevent GCC from complaining about no return value from the _trim function? I tried to disable the appropriate compiler warning, but I didn’t have much luck with that.

Here is my code:

```
// Trim all but digits from the string, return start of string.
void _trim(char *s) {
    char *d;

    // Save start of string for function return and set d=s.
    asm volatile (
        "mov %1, %0 \n" // Set d = s.
        "push %1"       // Save start of string for function return.
        : "=r" (d) : "r" (s)
    );
    // Ignore everything but digits...
    while (*s != '\0') {
        if (isdigit(*s))
            *d++ = *s;
        s++;
    }
    *d = '\0'; // Terminate string.
    asm volatile ( "pop %eax" ); // Retrieve beginning of string.
}

// Define weak alias to prevent gcc from squawking about no return value.
char *trim(char *) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("_trim")));
#endif

int main(void) {
    char line[80];

// ...
    if (strlen(trim(line)) == 8)
// Do something...
}
```

Comment: I understand this isn't the point of the question, but I would ask why you're using assembly here...

Comment: I second the question posed by Falcon. What are you tryign to achieve by using inline? As well pushing a value on the stack in inline assembly could yield the incorrect results if the code generated became relative to _ESP_. The compiler also has no idea that `asm volatile ( "pop %eax" )` is intended to return any value, and the function is `void` so it complains.

Comment: This code is fraught with so many issues (what you are doing won't reliably work), but if we assume for sake of argument you wanted to pop a value into EAX a have it as a return value - you'd change `void _trim` to `char *_trim` and define a return pointer like `char *retptr` in the function and then do this at the bottom `__asm__ __volatile__ ( "pop %0" : "=r"(retptr) :: "memory" ); return retptr;`

Comment: Some of us act like a broken record but this link has good advice: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm

Answer (score 3):

Your inline asm is just completely invalid.

1. You cannot leave an inline asm block with the stack pointer different from what it was when you entered. If you do, any subsequent access to the stack by the compiler will be wrong and all hell will break loose. You can't just "fix it in a later asm block" because you have no way to guarantee that the compiler makes no access to the stack in between. In your own example, you call `isdigit` in between, making a function call without respecting the function call ABI (that the stack must be aligned mod 16 at function call).
2. Loading a value into `eax` (or whatever the ABI's return-value register is) in a particular asm block **does not** return that value from the function. All it does is clobber a register that you told the compiler you would not clobber (you didn't include it in the clobber list for the asm block), thereby creating another reason all hell could break loose. If the compiler had some important value kept in that register (for example, the stack canary for ssp), and it gets a different value when reading it back, anything could happen. Even ignoring that breakage, there's no reason to think the value you put in `eax` will still be there when the function returns, or will serve as the function's return value. The compiler may load something else there before it actually returns, or make a transformation (inlining, or various inter-procedural optimizations based on having access to the definition of the function) such that the caller obtains the return value in some other way than what it would use when having made an external call to an unknown function matching the ABI.

The way you fix your code (minimizing changes in style) is:

```
char *trim(char *s) {
    char *d, *d0;

    d0 = d = s;

    // Ignore everything but digits...
    while (*s != '\0') {
        if (isdigit(*s))
            *d++ = *s;
        s++;
    }
    *d = '\0'; // Terminate string.

    return d0;
}
```

Comment: WRT #1: This is especially true if the code is compiled with `-fomit-frame-pointer`.

Comment: @duskwuff : and likely with any level of optimization turned on. Ultimately I think we all agree, what this OP is doing is not valid. But it does still interest me as to why he was doing all this. He must have been dealing with a problem that lead him down this path. I'd be curious to know what it was

Comment: In your update - the code you has the return type as void. Maybe you mean char *

Comment: @MichaelPetch: The problem was thinking (probably having been wrongly taught) that a temp variable is more expensive than pushing/popping on the stack.

Comment: Obviously a different compiler, but the eax idea came from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/writing-functions-with-inline-assembly

Comment: @JimEli: Microsoft's idea of inline asm is something completely different and utterly wrong in so many ways. It works (and fundamentally can only work) by turning the C compiler into an ultra-dumb high level assembler in the functions it's used in. GCC's inline asm on the other hand integrates with the AST and is compatible with arbitrarily-advanced optimizations, *but as a consequence* you have to tell it how the asm fits in, satisfy your side of the interface contract, and *not lie to it*.